# Glassfish Java App Class cast exception

Tags: java, glassfish-3, grizzly

Getting the following exception when casting

> fqe.dataHandler.LiveUpdateMessage cannot be cast to fqe.dataHandler.LiveUpdateMessage

Sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't. The object can never be anything other than that class.

If it helps this is when getting the Object from grizzly-comet's CometEvent.message() function on GlassFish 3.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually due in a Servlet Engine when you have two instances of a jar file being loaded by different ClassLoaders. Maybe one in a WAR and another in the classpath of the engine ?

Comment: Thanks mate, not sure the exact cause, but if i undeploy and redeploy from netbeans after every change in code it works. Bit of a pain but has solved the issue.